# What is the relevance of the fast-growing hierarchy in the definition of Yudkowsky’s number?

Tags: logic, ordinals, proof-theory, ordinal-analysis

I’m struggling with a certain connection the author draws in defining a certain “huge” number. The number is defined as follows:

Let T be the first-order theory of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory plus the Axiom of Choice plus the axiom that there exists an I0 rank-into-rank cardinal.

Starting with P = 10:

1. Search through all Turing machines with at most P states.
2. Search through all proofs in T of length at most 2^^P that the program halts.
3. Run all programs such that a halting proof exists, until they halt.
4. Add up all the running times of all those programs.
5. Set P to this sum.
6. Repeat 10 times.

This is claimed to be the biggest “kind” of number we could theoretically compute. I’m not sure I understand enough to say whether this is true, but the definition seems quite straightforward to me. However the author also then says:

“The end result should be roughly equal to the fast-growing hierarchy at the proof-theoretic ordinal of T, plus 1, applied to 10“

I don’t get this part. My understanding was that a theory’s proof-theoretic ordinal corresponded to the fastest-growing function in a fast-growing hierarchy which the theory could prove total - I’m not seeing the connection between the two at all, why would the above function behave like the fast-growing hierarchy at this particular ordinal?

Not sure if this is me missing a
deep intuitive connection/a lot
of the argument has been hand-waved over/the author is confused, but I’d really appreciate some insight

Answer (score 1):

Note that the $f_{PTO(T)}$ isn't *a priori* related to the functions $T$ proves total, as it isn't even defined without a system of fundamental sequences. However, it is generally believed that with respect to a 'natural' system of fundamental sequences (otherwise one could do some ridiculous system like "$\omega[n]=BB(n)$", with the busy beaver function) and 'natural' theories $T$ (otherwise, for a natural system of fundamental sequences and theory $T$, one can just add an axiom "$f_{PTO(T)+1}$ is total" without affecting the proof-theoretic ordinal), $f_{PTO(T)}$ is the first function in the fast-growing hierarchy that $T$ does not prove total.

Now let's consider how each execution of the loop affects $P$. the Turing machines that are run compute the functions $T$ proves total. To analyse how this affects $P$, we can *conjecture* that using $PTO(T)[n]=\sup \{\alpha:T\text{ proves }f_\alpha\text{ total with a proof of length at most }2\uparrow\uparrow n\}$ (note that this is a fundamental sequence by the first paragraph, the only question is how 'natural' it is). Then the execution times for the programs will be roughly around $f_{PTO(T)[P]}(P)$, and so it will map $P$ to $f_{PTO(T)[P]}(P)=f_{PTO(T)}(P)$. This means that after running the loop 10 times starting with $P=10$, the final value is roughly $f^{10}_{PTO(T)}(10)=f_{PTO(T)+1}(10)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - sorry for the delay. If I could just check I understand correctly: everything seems intuitive except the claim that the running time will add up to “around ()[]()”. Is the idea that the running time of this Turing Machine must be at least the value of the output of this function in order to write out the value, and that given the nature of the fast-growing hierarchy this value will dominate the sum of all the other running times, hence the “roughly”?